# Number of digits in a number?

Tags: java, time-complexity

i have written a program to find out the number of digit in a given number in java. Is it a good way to do it and what is the time complexity of the program:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Inst {
     /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
             double a = sc.nextDouble();
            for(int n=0;n<200000;n++)
            {
             double b=Math.pow(10, n);

             double d=a/b; 
            if(d>=0 & d<=9)
            {
                System.out.println("The number has "+(n+1)+" DIGITS");
                break;
            }
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: No this doesnt seem like a good way to do this to me, there is a lot of unnecessary operations. the scanner gives you a string, just check whether or not its an actual number and then count the number of char's

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;

public class JavaLength {
  public static void main(String[] args){ 
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   Double d = sc.nextDouble();
   String dString = d.toString();
   System.out.println(d);
   if(dString.contains(".")){
      System.out.println("Total Characters: " + (dString.length() -1 ));
   }else{
      System.out.println("Total Characters: " + (dString.length()));
   } /*-1 for the '.' in between, if it exists!*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
double input = Input;
int length = (input + "").length();
```

Comment: ya thanks but i want to make a program that can be implemented in any language.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, the most efficient way to test the number of (decimal) digits needed to represent an integer will be a tree of if / else tests.  The complexity will be `O(1)`, but the code will be UGLY (but portable); e.g.

```
int num = ...

if (num >= 0)
    if (num < 1000000)
        if (num < 10000)
            if (num < 100)
                if (num < 10)
                    return 1
                else
                    return 2
            else 
                ...
        else
            ...
    else 
        ...
else 
    ...
```

Comment: That's like claiming FFT is O(1), as any real input sequence is finite. In reality that solution is O(log n). I'm not sure though if it's ugly or not.

Comment: It is `O(log N)` where `N` is the largest possible value of the type of `num`.  For any primitive type, `N` will be a constant.  But the approach wouldn't work for types where `N` isn't a constant ... because that would imply a test tree whose size is not constant.

Comment: ... Therefore, it is justifiable in substituting for N and calling this `O(1)`.  (And it makes sense ... because time taken does NOT vary as `O(log N)` if `N` is the value of `num`!)  By constrast, the time taken to do an FFT depends on the size of the input array, and that is a runtime parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Using pow / log is not generally a good solution, as there may be a number close to a power of ten that rounds to the next integer. In double precision one should be able to precisely store all 15 digit numbers for which log10 should be absolutely < 15. In reality log10(10^15 - 100) still rounds to 15.

One will be stuck with the same algorithms, that are internally used in decimal to string conversions:

*trial division*:

```
while (i > 0) { i=i/10;  count++; }
```

*trial multiplication*:

```
j=10; while (i >= j) { j*=10; count++; }
```

*trial division from msb to lsb* converting to string;

```
j=10000000; while (i>0) { 
                 while (i>=j) { digit++;i-=j;}; 
                 j/=10; *str++=digit+'0'; digit=0:
            }
```

Binary to bcd conversion using [double dabble algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble) where each digit is represented by reduced set of hexadecimal digits (omitting a-f).

Answer (score 0):

This logic was originally written in c++, but i believe is the best way to find number of digits, store them in reverse order and find sum of digits.

```
int n;
int count=0, sum=0;
int j=0;
int ar[10];    //array to store digits

cin>> n;      //input number
do{
    if((n/10)==0){
        count++;
        ar[j]=n;
        break;
    }
    
    else{
        count++;
        ar[j]= (n%10);
        j++;
        n=int(n/10);
    }
}

`
while((n/10)!=0||(n%10)!=0);

cout<<"The number of digits is: "<<count<<"\n"<<"The reverse number is: ";

for(int u=0;u<count;u++){
    cout<<ar[u];
    sum+=ar[u];
}
cout<<"\n"<< "Sum of digits is: "<< sum;
}`
```